# Calculating historical Volatility for the Black Scholes Model

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes

Below is a problem from the book "Options, Futures, and other Derivatives" by
John C. Hull. I did the problem but I am fairly sure that my answer is wrong. I
am hoping that somebody can tell me where I went wrong?
Thanks,
Bob

Problem:
Suppose that observations on a stock price(in dollars) at the end of each
$15$ consecutive weeks are as follows:
$30.2$, $32.0$, $31.1$, $30.1$, $30.2$, $30.3$, $30.6$, $33.0$,
$32.9$, $33.0$, $33.5$, $33.5$, $33.7$, $33.5$, $33.2$
Estimate the stock price volatility.
Answer:
Let the closing prices be denoted by $S$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
u_i &=& \ln{  \bigg( \frac {S_1}  {S_{i-1}} \bigg) } \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Using R, I find that:
\begin{eqnarray*}
u &=& 0.057893978 \,\, -0.028528084 \,\, -0.032682647 \\
   && 0.003316753 \,\, -0.006644543 \,\, -2.302585093 \\
 && 2.322387720 \,\, 0.075507553 \,\, -0.003034904 \\
    && 0.003034904 \,\, 0.015037877 \,\, 0.000000000 \\
 && 0.005952399 \,\, -0.005952399 \,\, -0.008995563 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now using $R$, I find that the standard deviation of $u$ is $0.8744864$. Call that value $s$. I will call the volatility of the stock to be $\sigma$. Now let $\tau$ be the length of time we observed the
value of the stock for.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sigma &=&\frac{s}{\sqrt{\tau}} \\
\tau &=& \frac{14}{52} = 0.2692308 \\
\sigma &=& \frac{0.8744864}{\sqrt{ 0.2692308}} \\
\sigma &=& 1.6853523 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
This number seems way off to me. What did I do wrong?
It also seems strange to me that in the last step you are dividend by
$\sqrt{\tau}$ but that is the procedure given in the book.

Comment: Assuming your prices are correct, then 3 of your u values are wildly incorrect namely -0.00664, -2.3025, 2.32238. These should be 0.0033058 0.0098523 0.0755076

Comment: When I did the calculations in R, I entered $30.3$ as $30$,$.3$. I now fixed this typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this sound more reasonable?

[image]

To annualise the weekly std dev, you need to multiply by the square root of 52.

Let me know if you spot any typo.

Re-comment, 14 is the number of return observations, so it is already incorporated in the calculation of weekly std dev (2.88%). I think the author might have implied that if the observations that you use for stddev calculations have an interval of tau in years (daily=1/252, weekly=1/52, monthly=1/12), then you divide the computed std dev by sqrt(tau), which is sqrt(1/52) in your case. Now dividing by 1/sqrt(52) is same as multiplying by sqrt(52), and that’s exactly the factor you need to multiply 2.88% by to get the answer.

Comment: I follow your calculations up and including the 2.88%. What I do not see is how you go from the 2.88% to the 20.79%.  The way I would do it is to divide by the $\sqrt{( \tau )}$ where $\tau$ is $14/52$.

Comment: Multiplying the stdev by $\sqrt{52}$ looks fine. The ratio $14/52$ should only be used when you are starting from the sum of squares (not the stdev).

Comment: Thanks @noob2! I have added explanation in the answer.

Comment: @Magic is in the chain  Now I think I get it, you divided by $\sqrt{\tau}$ where $\tau = 7/365$ because we making the observation once a week. Is that right?

Comment: Yes! 52 weeks in a year, roughly!

Answer (score 0):

The division is correct but more often you’ll find a multiplication by the inverse of $\sqrt{\tau}$ instead.

Your vector of returns $u$ has gone wrong somehow, there is simply no way you would have numbers over the 0.05 area with the prices provided.

Additionally you would calculate the standard deviation of $\ln{\frac{S_i}{S_{i-1}}}$, do you have a typo there or a logical error ?

Comment: I do have an error there. Thanks for pointing it out.